# Passing Method as a Character String

Tags: r

I need to allow the user to create an object with one of several classes. The object will require further analysis so will be passed to one of numerous S3 methods downstream.

My thought is to have them provide the class as a character string on the creation function call, but I'm not sure the best way to use useMethod to select the proper S3 method, since the different objects will be created with different algorithms.

The create_thing() function will return an object with class set, so graph_thing() and report_thing() will take the output of create_thing() and have a class to work with.

```
create_thing <- function(model = 'strange', foo, bar){
  tmp <- ""
  class(tmp)<-model
  UseMethod("create_thing", tmp)
}

create_thing.strange <- function(model, foo = 1, bar = 2){
  ## stuff
  print("strange")
  return(structure(list(data=runif(5)), class = c("list", "strange")))
}

create_thing.normal <- function(model, foo = 3, bar = 4){
  ## stuff
  print("normal")
  return(structure(list(data=rnorm(5)), class = c("list", "normal")))
}

graph_thing <- function(athing){
  UseMethod("graph_thing")
}

graph_thing.normal <- function(athing){
  print("normal")
  plot(athing$data)
}

graph_thing.strange <- function(athing){
  print("strange")
  plot(athing$data)
}

report_thing <- function(athing){
  UseMethod("report_thing")
}

report_thing.normal <- function(athing){
  print("normal")
  print(mean(athing$data))
}

report_thing.strange <- function(athing){
  print("strange")
  print(median(athing$data))
}
```

Comment: The proper way to use `UseMethod` is via standard `S3` dispatch, which is handled under the hood if the object class is set correctly. I'm not entirely clear on the reasons for your example to exist, can you give more details on what you are trying to do? What objects might someone pass in?

Comment: I *think* what you're trying to do could be accomplished if you defined a standard generic `thing = function(foo, bar) {UseMethod("thing")}` and then did whatever weird things you are currently doing in your version of `thing` in `thing.default` instead, with it's last line being to call `thing()` on it... assuming you've changed the class to something with a different `thing` method. But it does seem like you're running yourself in circles.

Comment: Maybe you just need to define an `as.strange` and expect users to use that? Y'know, like S3 classes usually work? The mentions of `graph_thing` and `report_thing` are confusing in your text since they don't seem to line up with your example code. Do you mean `graph.thing` and `report.thing`? Is `thing` your class, or are `strange` and `normal` different classes?

Comment: There seems to be serious object/function confusion here.  The last call in a function determines what is returned. `UseMethod("thing", tmp)` returns ....  a function. And it's unclear what `thing.strange` and `thing.normal` are supposed to be doing because they coded as empty, return a character object and _most_ _importantly_ are not described in natural language. Please improve the question.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly question, I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1):

The `UseMethod` function looks up the call stack to see what was passed in to the original function. Any modifications or new objects created will not influence how dispatching works.

If you are using the `create_thing` functions to initilize the object, then you should create a separate generic function for that

```
create_thing <- function(model = 'strange', foo, bar){
  tmp <- ""
  class(tmp)<-model
  init_thing(tmp, foo, bar)
}

init_thing <- function(model, foo=0, bar=0) {
    UseMethod("init_thing")
}
init_thing.strange <- function(model, foo = 1, bar = 2){
  ## stuff
  print("strange")
  return(structure(list(data=runif(5)), class = c("list", "strange")))
}

init_thing.normal <- function(model, foo = 3, bar = 4){
  ## stuff
  print("normal")
  return(structure(list(data=rnorm(5)), class = c("list", "normal")))
}
```